# Get foreign key column with a pivot table in between the first two arguments of a user I.E. Auth::user()->account->job

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Ok so I have been googling this a lot and found nothing.
How do I take the Auth::user() object then get all accounts for that user with a pivot then get a sub item say jobs.
so.

```
//gets me the user object
$user = Auth::user();
//pivot table  account_user
//gets me all the users accounts
$accounts = $user->account()->get();
//this gets me all the accounts with the correct jobs
$accounts =  Account::with('job')->get();

class Account extends Model{
    public function user() {return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('a','b','c','d')->withTimestamps();} 
    public function job(){return $this->belongsTo('App\Job');}
}
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,AuthorizableContract,CanResetPasswordContract{
 public function account(){return $this->belongsToMany('App\Account')->withPivot('a','b','c','d')->withTimestamps();
}
```

So I am wanting the all the accounts the user has and on each of them I want the job_id they have replaced with the foreign column name or able to get to it from the json object it makes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to use the with on the accounts model like so.
$accounts = $user->account()->with('Financialinstitution')->get();